# Why a balloon explodes by itself?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, material-science, elasticity

I was wondering why a balloon explodes after some time by itself with no specific reason.
yesterday I was doing my chores and to my amazement the balloon far in the corner of house pop with no obvious reason.(the temperature had not changed before its explosion/usual conditions)
I mean atmospheric pressure and pressure in balloon and force which balloon itself pushes are in an equilibrium. So what happens?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41521/

Comment: Try to look for similar questions on the website before asking your own

Comment: my question was a bit different

Comment: sorry for my bad English

Comment: I clarified  my question .

Answer (score 0):

I think that since the balloon is in tension all the time so the molecular bonds go weaker and weaker so it explodes at last.

Comment: This is essentially correct. Nanoscopic tears may form under the tension. And once they form, the stress causes them to grow until...POP!!